# Signals between pages

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to communicate between 2 QML pages. 
In my page `Main.qml` I receive a signal from my C++ code. On receiving this signal I want text on `InputPage.qml` to change. This page is shown within `Main.qml` using a `Loader`. The only way I could find so far is to set up another signal between the 2 pages. However, I think there is a much easier way to do this. I already tried this way but I could not get it to work. So before I proceed I would like to know if this is the right method or not.

Any ideas on how to do this, and if the method described above is the correct one?

My code:

**Main.qml**

```
Item {
    id: screen_InputPage
    width: 1920
    height: 930
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: 0
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 100
    visible: false
    opacity: 1
    Loader {//Loads the pages
        id: pageLoader_ID2
        source: "inputPage.qml"
    }
}
```

And i would like to access the text(and maybe functions) placed on **inputPage.qml**

```
Text {
    id: text_volume_perc_ID1
    height: 48
    text: qsTr("50")
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.rightMargin: 0
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 126
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: 0
    font.pixelSize: 42
}
```

Comment: `Loader` has an [`item`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#item-prop). You can use that to access text item (if top level) or define an `alias` or define a function inside `InputPage.qml` which updates the text. In the latter case you would write in the `Connections` code something like <loader_id>.item.<function()>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the created object, you can use

```
idLoader.item.idInputpage.idText.text
```

I propose that you load objects dynamically to improve performance. To do so you can create your own `CustomLoader.qml`:

### CustomLoader.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: idRoot
    width: childrenRect.width
    height: childrenRect.height

    property Item createdObject
    property string source

    function fnSourceChange() {
        if (""!== source){
            var component
            // create component
            component = Qt.createComponent(source)
            if (Component.Ready === component.status) {
                createdObject= component.createObject(idRoot)
                if(!createdObject)
                    console.log("Loader::Could not create the object ")
            }
            else {
                console.log("Loader::Could not create panel", component.errorString(), "component has errors")
            }
        }
        else {
            createdObject.destroy();
            createdObject = null
            // unComment this line if you want to force the garbage collector
            //gc()
        }
    }

    onSourceChanged: {
        fnSourceChange()
    }
    // even without that it should detect the source change and create it
    // you can unComment this line if you want, but like that it will parse the function
    // two times one on the sourceChanged signal and on on in this handler
    // print the source or somthing in the function and you'll see
    // Component.onCompleted: fnSourceChange()

}
```

### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: screen_InputPage
    width: 1920
    height: 930
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: 0
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 100
    visible: false
    opacity: 1

    CustomLoader{
        id: pageLoader_ID2
        source: "inputPage.qml"
    }
}
```

### InputPage.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 800
    height: 480
    property alias text: idText.text
    property alias label: idText
    property alias rect: idRect
    Text{
        id: idText
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: idRect
        width: 100
        height: 200
    }
}
```

In your main add :

```
//or another scope like click button
Component.onCompleted: {

    pageLoader_ID2.createdObject.text = "hello"
    pageLoader_ID2.createdObject.rect.color = "red"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying your method now. But when i add those lines to my code it does not display the page anymore. I already figured out it is the **property string source** which causes that. I will add my code to my post. Could you tell me how and where to implement your suggestion? Also i don't change the source. So will the createComponent still be created even though i do not change the source (will the source change when the component is created be enough?)

Comment: hi, I'll post the code , you should creat a new Item you can name it CustomLoader, yes the source Change will be enough cause the default source of the loader is empty, then when you affect a string to it, the sourceChange signal will be sent.

Comment: I implemented it in my code(made a separate CustomLoader.qml file and changed Loader to CustomLoader in main.qml) but when i call **pageLoader_ID2.text_volume_perc_ID1.text = "Test"** it gives the error: "TypeError: Type error" in that line. Any idea what i doing wrong?

Comment: you should write `pageLoader_ID2.createdObject.text = "Test" `. now your object is createdObject, you cant access it by it's id you should always pass by createdObject to access it's properties and aliasis

Comment: But how can i interact with the **text_volume_perc_ID1** because i have id1 trough id32.
When i use pageLoader_ID2.createdObject.text = "Test" it says: "Error: Cannot assign to non-existent property "text""

Comment: I 'll post an example code in my answer, it will clarify things for you

Comment: @Martijn please see the end of my answer post, you can access object by creating aliasis

Comment: Aah that was what i was looking for! Didn't think of aliases yet. It works like a charm! Thank you very much!